# jsconfig paths resolve not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, eslint

```js
import { checkToken } from '@/util/token.js';
```

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@/util' imported from

**jsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "root": "true",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

**.eslintrc.cjs**

```js
settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
      },
    },
  },
```

Why that not work?

Comment: It's not `@util/token.js` ? (witout the /)

Comment: No. @/util/token.js — my js module